# How to appear offline on Facebook, to all but one person?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-privacy

Sometimes Facebook is the best or only method of communication between her and a priority contact. So as not to seem rude to her other friends, customers, or whatever while she's busy; how can she appear offline to everyone except her current client?

Apparently, you can create a list of contacts and appear offline to them at any time, but a large list will be long and painful to compose manually.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off chat for all contacts except *that* person.

Here you go:

- Login to [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)
- Click on **Options** (gear icon) in the chat section, on the bottom right side
- Select **Turn Off Chat**
- Select **Turn off chat for all contacts except...**
- Click on **Okey**

Do the same thing to **Turn Off Video/voice Calls**

After above changes you (or her) will be offline for all your contacts except whom you have selected.

Comment: Do you know if the same thing is possible with the Android/iOS apps?

Comment: No, I don't know. I think from mobile app that is not possible (I'm not sure). And if your question is related to Android/iOS apps, then it will be off topic here. This site is specifically for web application end user. Take a [tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Well, it's basically just an interface for the web app. The back end is the same. There's not much I can do about the relationship between the two. Without being pedantic, the question is about neither interface in particular; both are within it's scope. Rarely does anything in life fit neatly into a single category. Anyhow, thanks for the assist, I'll report back with our successes and/or failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following these simple steps:

1. go to: https://www.facebook.com and login to your account if you aren't logged in already.
2. Click on options "gear icon" on the bottom right corner next to the search field.
3. Check "Turn off chat for all contacts except.." box and type the name for the contact you don't want to turn the chat off for, select it and click okay.

That should be it.